# How do I make a subroutine name passed as argument available throughout module?

Tags: fortran, arguments, subroutine, fortran95

I would like to use a variable subroutine name, and I would like this name to be available throughout a module, not just in a single subroutine.

A variable subroutine name passed as an argument is a type of data. Where is it stored? How can I access it?

Here is more explanation. G is a nonlinear fitting routine. H uses G but with grouping of parameters (iteration moving one group at a time). G uses a general forward model subroutine whose name is passed as an argument. I would like H to preserve this generality.

Here is the test program using a workaround with a hardcoded subroutine name:

```
  module G_MOD
  implicit none
  character(len=30)::message='Good Morning'

  contains

  subroutine G(Sub)
  external::Sub
  call Sub
  end subroutine G

  end module G_MOD

  module H_MOD
  use G_MOD
  implicit none

  contains

  subroutine H(sub)
  external:: sub
  call G(LocalSub)
  end subroutine H

  subroutine LocalSub
  external:: MySub
  message='Good Afternoon'
  call G(MySub) ! the subroutine name "MySub" is hardcoded
                ! I would like it to be argument sub
  end subroutine LocalSub

  end module H_MOD

  program test
  use H_MOD
  implicit none
  external MySub
  call H(MySub)
  end program test

  subroutine MySub
  use G_MOD,only:message
  write(*,*)trim(Message)
  end subroutine MySub
```

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions to get more attention.

Comment: Don't use external when you have modules. There are good ways in Fortran 2003. Do you require strict old Fortran 95 for some reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i modify a procedure name passed as an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478369/how-do-i-modify-a-procedure-name-passed-as-an-argument)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

You don't need to store anything if you make `LocalSub` internal to `H`:

```
  subroutine H(sub)
    external:: sub
    call G(LocalSub)
  contains
    subroutine LocalSub
      message='Good Afternoon'
      call G(sub)
    end subroutine LocalSub
  end subroutine H
```

It requires Fortran 2008.

With some cleanup, indentation for readability, removing the ugly externals using an abstract interface (Fortran 2003, but `external` can be avoided even in Fortran 90 using interface blocks) the code is:

```
  module G_MOD
    implicit none
    character(len=30)::message='Good Morning'

    abstract interface
      subroutine sub_interface
      end subroutine
    end interface

  contains

    subroutine G(Sub)
      procedure(sub_interface) :: sub
      call Sub
    end subroutine G

  end module G_MOD

  module H_MOD
    use G_MOD
    implicit none

  contains

    subroutine H(sub)
      procedure(sub_interface) :: sub
      call G(LocalSub)
    contains
      subroutine LocalSub

        message='Good Afternoon'
        call G(sub) 
      end subroutine LocalSub
    end subroutine H

  end module H_MOD

  program test
    use H_MOD
    implicit none


    call H(MySub)
  contains
    subroutine MySub
      use G_MOD,only:message
      write(*,*)trim(Message)
    end subroutine MySub
  end program test
```

---

### Solution 2

If you really want to store a reference to the procedure in a module, it is possible, but remember **global variables are UGLY**. What if you want to make multiple calls to your optimization in parallel?

So, you can store the address (not name) of a procedure in a `procedure pointer`. These require Fortran 2003. A minimal change of your code is

```
  module H_MOD
    use G_MOD
    implicit none

    procedure, pointer :: stored_sub => null()

  contains

    subroutine H(sub)
      external:: sub
      stored_sub => sub
      call G(LocalSub)
    end subroutine H

    subroutine LocalSub
      message='Good Afternoon'
      call G(stored_sub)
    end subroutine LocalSub

  end module H_MOD
```

but much better modern code is:

```
  module G_MOD
    implicit none
    character(len=30)::message='Good Morning'

    abstract interface
      subroutine sub_interface
      end subroutine
    end interface

  contains

    subroutine G(Sub)
      procedure(sub_interface) :: sub
      call Sub
    end subroutine G

  end module G_MOD

  module H_MOD
    use G_MOD
    implicit none

    procedure(sub_interface), pointer :: stored_sub => null()

  contains

    subroutine H(sub)
      procedure(sub_interface) :: sub
      stored_sub => sub
      call G(LocalSub)

    end subroutine H

    subroutine LocalSub

      message='Good Afternoon'
      call G(stored_sub) 
    end subroutine LocalSub

  end module H_MOD


  module MySub_module
  contains
    subroutine MySub
      use G_MOD,only:message
      write(*,*)trim(Message)
    end subroutine MySub
  end module MySub_module

  program test
    use H_MOD
    use MySub_module
    implicit none


    call H(MySub)
  end program test
```

Still, I *definitely* prefer the variant with the internal procedure.

And remember, **use indentation**, it is essential for readable code.

Comment: what happens if you modify it?

Comment: The modification is question is to add the line          call stored_sub
before the line           call G(stored_sub). This should function the same and result in two "Good Afternoon" messages. However it causes the compile to fail with G95 but not with Intel (In file solution2.for:36
          call stored_sub
               1
Error: Symbol 'stored_sub' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type.

Comment: Some bug in G95. Forget G95, it is old and no longer supported. Use gfortran instead.